# Answer in search of a question

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I have again been tempted to answer a bad question with an encyclopedia-style answer. ([Questions regarding the distinction between XeTeX and XeLaTeX and how they relate to TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296616)) 
Would it be better to post this as an additional answer to the linked dupe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The network is designed to link questions that have a reference added (either in comment or in the posts), so there's no issue with adding an answer in either location. See the right-hand column when viewing the question to see which posts it may be linked to. Note that the answer has to be just that, an answer to the question.

With the broader picture in mind, it may be of more interest to add encyclopedia-style answers to the "bigger question", whichever that may be. Of course, this may be subjective as some may see the bigger question as the one with the most views/up-votes, while others may see it as the question with the most duplicate targets.

While this doesn't matter now, the mentioned question has already been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I moved my answer, slightly edited, to this question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines/296966#296966), which was linked as a duplicate of the one I answered. But I can't delete the one on the old question since the OP accepted it.

Comment: I could edit down the original answer to something very minimal and point to the moved answer, but that seems to go against the idea that the OP accepted the previous answer.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Yes, that wasn't considered in the question - you can't remove content once it's accepted. My suggestion would be a keep things as they are, since the two posts are linked.

Comment: Got it- that makes sense.

Comment: I left a comment on the bigger question pointing to my answer on the dupe. In the future I'll try to be more discerning to begin with about which questions to answer.